# Spaces where distance between a point and a hyperplane is always reached

Tags: normed-spaces

In [this](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/distance-between-a-point-and-a-hyperplane-not-reached/) article I give an example of a Banach space where the distance between a point and a hyperplane is not reached.

In the same [article](http://bit.ly/1z2C2c4), I mention that for finite dimensional vector spaces or Hilbert spaces, the distance between a point and a closed hyperplane is always reached.

What are other "types" of vector spaces for which the distance between a point and a closed hyperplane is always reached?

Comment: It holds for any reflexive space. (Closed convex sets are weakly closed. Thus bounded, closed, convex sets are weakly compact in reflexive spaces. The norm is weakly lower semi-continuous.)